# How to recreate json object

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have json object like this

```
[
      {
        "name": "first_name",
        "value": "sssssssssssssssssss"
      },{
        "name": "email",
        "value": "ss.ss@gmail.com"
      }, {
        "name": "address",
        "value": "ssssssssssssssssssss"
      }, {
        "name": "PhoneNumber",
        "value": "12342123321"
      }     
    ]
```

This data is coming on form subbmission

But i want json data as

```
{
    "formProperties": {
        "table": "users",
        "mode": "insert",
        "method":"post",
        "action":"urlhere",
        "user":"admin"
  },
    "formValues": [
      {
        "name": "first_name",
        "value": "sssssssssssssssssss"
      },{
        "name": "email",
        "value": "ss.ss@gmail.com"
      }, {
        "name": "address",
        "value": "ssssssssssssssssssss"
      }, {
        "name": "PhoneNumber",
        "value": "12342123321"
      }     
    ]
}
```

How to reconstruct JSON object. please help me friends I was strucked with this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `JSON.parse` and then construct the object by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Assume the JSON as string is saved in the variable called `json` you can use the following code:

```
var newObject = {
    "formProperties": {
        "table": "users",
        "mode": "insert",
        "method":"post",
        "action":"urlhere",
        "user":"admin"
    },
    "formValues": JSON.parse(json)
};

var newJson = JSON.stringify(newObject);
```